# Why does returning Promise.resolve() inside `then` cause two promise creation instead of one?

Tags: javascript, promise

Actually, I don't know how to check this on real Promise super class, so I'm testing it with a class extending it. But it seems to me the result would be the same.

```
class PromisePlus extends Promise {
  constructor (handler) {
    super(handler)

    console.log('new promise created')
  }
}

new PromisePlus((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve()
}).then(() => {
  return 'GOOD'
}).then(msg => {
  console.log(msg)
})
```

prints 'new promise created' 3 times

```
new PromisePlus((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve()
}).then(() => {
  return PromisePlus.resolve('BAD')
}).then(msg => {
  console.log(msg)
})
```

prints 'new promise created' 5 times.

The same result with returning new Promise inside `then` handler

```
new PromisePlus((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve()
}).then(() => {
  return new PromisePlus((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('BAD')
  })
}).then(msg => {
  console.log(msg)
})
```

Obviously, `PromisePlus.resolve()` creates new promise, but why does returning `PromisePlus.resolve()` inside `then` cause one more extra promise creation?

Comment: Because you are returning a new Promise when using `Promise.resolve`. You can return a new promise rejecting as well `Promise.reject(new Error("some error"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: @zero298 That has nothing to do with this question. He's asking about using [Promise.resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)  inside a `then` callback. Specifically wondering why that creates two new promises. How the original promise was created is irrelevant, and it makes sense to use the Promise constructor for a MCVE.

Comment: He could've asked why `PromisePlus.resolve( ).then( _ => PromisePlus.resolve() )` creates four promises if he wanted to avoid the Promise constructor, but it's the same question and that duplicate doesn't answer it.

Comment: Every `.then()` or `.catch()` returns a new promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, that is why 4 new promise creation was expected, but not 5

Answer (score 4):

> Why does returning `PromisePlus.resolve()` inside then cause one more extra promise creation?

Because when you are returning a promise from a `then` callback, it does get awaited to resolve the outer promise (the one returned from `.then()`). To await this inner promise, `.then(…)` gets called on it - and this call does create a new promise as well.

(Yes, all this is horribly inefficient, which is probably the #1 reason why promise subclassing should be avoided).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Will they also remove recursive assimilation?

Comment: No of course not - people are actually using that. Not that I think they'd build it with it today.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I meant repeated attempts to recursively assimilate already-fulfilled promises, not recursive assimilation in general (in `Promise.resolve`)